# Property undefined, caused by no rows for sql query, how to ignore/avoid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**UPDATE**
Moving `data = JSON.parse(data);` out of the loop fixed the problem. It doesn'throw an error now and rest of my script executes. Thank you @George for the observation!

Original post:

I have ajax function that request some data from database but sometimes there won't be any data to my specification and that's fine. But now what happens is because php returns nothing to ajax then the value of my data is undefined and thus causing javascript error "Cannot read property '1' of undefined" and that causes rest of my script to not work.

```
function get_ajastatud2(onwait) {
var x=0;
$.ajax({
  url:"graphfunctions.php?func=5",  
  async:false,
  type:"POST",

  success:function(data) {
     for (var i = 0; i <data.length; i++){
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        var d2 = Date.createFromMysql(data[i][1]);
     }
}
```

There is more code in the success put what causes the error is the `var d2` line. The code works when I get results to my sql query. If you need any other code snippets like from my php or whatever, let me know.

Now my question is how to either avoid this issue correctly or how to ignore the error or what should I do in this situation?

Comment: What does `console.log(data)` show in your success function?

Comment: @Shilly That's not needed surely, if `data.length == 0` it wouldn't enter the loop.

Comment: Why are you parsing the data in the loop? `data = JSON.parse(data);`?

Comment: @Shilly If `data.length` is zero, it won't enter the `for` loop. So the additional check you mention in your first comment won't change anything. Checking on `data[i].length` won't work either because it could have a length and not have `data[i][1]` so both your comments can be removed as they will **not** help OP to resolve the issue.

Comment: @George That's a good observation, I didn't even think about it. I'll move the data parsing out of the loop.

Comment: In your function after success:function(data) {, add if( data != undefined && data.length > 0 ) { around the contents of the function.

Comment: @SPlatten No. Again. This is not going to fix anything! If `data` was empty or undefined, it would **not** enter the for loop.

Comment: You can't reassign data inside the for loop, this will break the loop as data will no longer be an array but an object.